# SESSION loss when using IE 11, no SESSION loss in other browsers

Tags: php, html, session-cookies

After eading so must about how some browsers use or don't use session variables I am totally confused. I have a script that has a iFrame, on the iFrame there is a user input form. When the form is completed and the save button is clicked, the input is saved to my data table or not, depending on which browser is being used. Works using Chrome and Firefox, does not work when using IE 11.

Now from what I have read its all to do with P3P Policies. Again, from the articles I have read there are many ways of dealing with P3P when using IE 11, but none I have tried work.

In my PHP scripts I have:

```
header('P3P: CP="ALL DSP COR CUR ADM TAI OUR IND COM NAV INT"');
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
   session_start();
}

// and so no
```

I have also read that just including:

```
header('P3P: CP="Potato"');
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

should work, none do.

It seams that this is only an issue with IE. Can anyone give me some advice and heml to get my scripts to work without any session loss.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: P3P is no longer supported in Win10/IE11. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt146424(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ceejayoz  I am using Win7/IE11 and so are alot of users. Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: I don't know exactly how Microsoft manages IE, but I'd guess if it's gone in IE11 on Windows 10 it's gone in all versions of IE11. Even it that's not true, your Win10/IE11 users are definitely affected, and it'll only get worse in the future. Sessions in third-party iframes have been problematic in other browsers like Safari for years - you simply can't rely on it.

Comment: @ceejayoz The iFrames are apart of my site, are they classed as third party? Microsoft say, P3P is not support any longer in Win10/IE11, not all other versions of IE11.

Comment: Define "a part of my site". `subdomain.example.com` and `example.com` are two different domains, as would one being HTTP and the other being HTTPS. P3P is only relevant in your scenario if we're discussing a cross-domain iframe. Why do you need an iframe if they're on the same domain?

Comment: @ceejayoz All my web pages sit on the same server. As an example, I have a page "index_conf.php" which has an iFrame "index_conf_iframe.php, index_conf_php in the root of the site and "index_conf_iframe.php" in a sub directory of the root, all part of my site. If I run "index_conf.php" the iframe opens with a user form, complete the form and save which runs a script conf_save.php to save the data to a table. Any session variables in in the "index_conf_iframe.php" script get passed the "conf_save.php". All this works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11.